# Build single column list from 4 columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm building a dropdown list for a web form. The format of the parent and child items in the form is very specific and follows the following pattern

```
Parent
-Child 1
--Child 2
---Child 3
```

(Hyphen equal to whitespace)

I have been handed an Excel spreadsheet containing the data with a short example below...

| Province | Island | Area Council | Water System |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Malampa | Malekula | Central Malekula | WS_Aim |
| Malampa | Malekula | South East Malekula | WS_Aktep |
| Malampa | Malekula | North East Malekula | WS_Alavas |
| Malampa | Malekula | North West Malekula | WS_Albatei |
| Malampa | Malekula | North West Malekula | WS_Alemtu |
| Malampa | Malekula | North West Malekula | WS_Alkakau |
| Malampa | Malekula | North West Malekula | WS_Anuatakh |
| Malampa | Malekula | South East Malekula | WS_Aout Veil |
| Malampa | Ambrym | South East Ambrym | WS_Ase |
| Malampa | Malekula | South East Malekula | WS_Asorok |
| Malampa | Malekula | South East Malekula | WS_Assen |
| Penama | Pentecost | North Pentecost | WS_Nambwarangiut |
| Penama | Ambae | West Ambae | WS_Nanako |
| Penama | Maewo | North Maewo | WS_Nandunga |
| Penama | Ambae | West Ambae | WS_Nangweangwea |
| Sanma | Malo | East Malo | WS_Naviova |
| Sanma | Santo | North Santo | WS_Navnaurota |
| Sanma | Santo | South Santo | WS_Navota Farm |
| Sanma | Santo | North Santo | WS_Nawelala |
| Sanma | Malo | West Malo | WS_Nawiambu |
| Sanma | Santo | North West Santo | WS_Nokuku |

I would like to know how best to format this data into the required pattern using Excel. I'm happy using a formula, a VLOOKUP and or VBA.

The output of the example data would be as follows...

```
    Malampa
     Ambrym
      South East Ambrym
       WS_Ase
     Malekula
      Central Malekula
       WS_Aim
      North East Malekula
       WS_Alavas
      North West Malekula
       WS_Albatei
       WS_Alemtu
       WS_Alkakau
       WS_Anuatakh
      South East Malekula
       WS_Aktep
       WS_Aout Veil
       WS_Asorok
       WS_Assen
    Penama
     Ambae
      West Ambae
       WS_Nambwarangiut
       WS_Nanako
       WS_Nangweangwea
     Maewo
      North Maewo
       WS_Nandunga
     Pentecost
      North Pentecost
       WS_Nambwarangiut
    Sanma
     Malo
       WS_Naviova
      West Malo
       WS_Nawiambu
      North Santo
       WS_Navnaurota
       WS_Nawelala
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't use `VLOOKUP`, but either formulas or `VBA` or even `Power Query` should work. What have you tried? This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with complex formulas or code you are trying to develop. I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then either edit your original question to improve it, or ask a new one if the original has been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit different from what I usually see here, so I thought I’d take a look at it in terms of a VBA solution.  I’m sure there’s a more elegant solution to the example I’ve given below, but this is what I came up with.

It assumes your data is on `Sheet1`, in columns `A:D`, and that the rest of the sheet is available for use as helper columns etc.  The desired output is put in column `F`.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ParentChild()
On Error GoTo GetOut
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, rng As Range, c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Create a copy of the data to restore to the original format
Sheet1.Range("A1:D" & LastRow).Copy Sheet1.Range("K1")

'Concatenate with delimiter, add spaces, sort & replace cols A:D values
'using the built-in TextToColumns function
With Sheet1.Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC1&"", ""&RC2&"",  ""&RC3&"",   ""&RC4"
    .Value = .Value
    .Sort Key1:=Sheet1.Range("F2"), order1:=xlAscending
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1))
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Clear
End With

'Delete sequential 'parents'
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A2:D" & LastRow)

For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
If rng.Item(i) = rng.Item(i).Offset(-1) Then
    rng.Item(i).ClearContents
End If
Next i

Sheet1.Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 25

'Copy to new column
i = 2
For Each c In Sheet1.Range("A2:D" & LastRow)
    If c.Value = "" Then GoTo Skip
        c.Copy Sheet1.Cells(i, 6)
        i = i + 1
Skip:
Next c

'Restore original format
Sheet1.Range("K1:N" & LastRow).Copy Sheet1.Range("A1")
Sheet1.Range("K1:N" & LastRow).Clear

Continue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
GetOut:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Continue

End Sub
```

Comment: This is an amazing response and I can't thank you enough. Works great and has taught me so much too. Cheers, Kevin!

Comment: My pleasure Ben.